# How to detect current iOS is 4.1 or 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

I tried with this code:

```
#if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_2_2)
    NSLog(@"iPhone 4.2");
#endif
```

but when I run it again on simulator 4.1, I still get the log "iPhone 4.2" in console.

Thanks for helping me.

Tung Do

Comment: Both 4.1 and 4.2 are ≥ 2.2.

Comment: #if/#endif are *compile-time* directives. All they do is compare against your build settings to see what OS version you are targeting. But the same code will be output regardless of what OS you run on. You want a *run-time* check.

Comment: Try this one : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/check-device-os-version.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should probably avoid asking about the system version altogether.

A better design would ask about a specific feature.

For instance: `if (NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInfo"))` would tell you if the current device supports the printing API,available in 4.2 or higher.

That way you can plan your code to use a feature if it's available, on not based on the OS version.

Answer (score 21):

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
```

Comment: Thanks. This code works as expected but I think Zigfried's solution is more flexible.

Comment: check this post it has good answer http://www.techpaa.com/2012/11/best-way-checking-iphone-ios-version.html

Answer (score 6):

Or, even better:

`CGFloat systemVersion = [[[ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ];`

Then, you can do a simple equality check, e.g.

`if( systemVersion > 4.1 ){...}`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this either at compile time or at runtime.

For compile time, you use the so-called availability macros:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > 40000 // __IPHONE_4_0
    NSLog( @"After Version 4.0" ); 
#else
    NSLog( @"Version 4.0 or earlier" ); 
#endif
```

However, the problem with compile-time is that you have to maintain multiple binaries.  If you want this binary to run on pre-4.x, then you should weak link to the iOS libraries.

```
if(kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber > kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_4_0)
{
    NSLog( @"After Version 4.0" ); 
}
else
{
    NSLog( @"Version 4.0 or earlier" ); 
}
```

There's a good tutorial here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html

Comment: yes, but I want to detect the iPhone 4.2 with the other.

Answer (score 3):

Rule 1: Do not depend on version or device type to determine if a feature is available. Different devices *(iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad)* can get the same feature but at different versions of the OS.
Link weakly against frameworks and missing classes will be `nil`. Or use `NSClassFromString()` function that also returns `nil` if a class do not exist. Also use `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]` to query if a method exists or not.

Rule 2: Apple discourages from using the defined constants *(such as `__IPHONE_2_2`)* when checking for versions, instead use their numerical values as such:

```
#if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40200)
   NSLog(@"BUILT against iPhone 4.2 or later");
#endif
```

But do take notice using `#if` compile-time directive will only check what version of the SDK you **build against** not which version of the OS will later **run on**.

Comment: this code will be run even in iPhone 4.0 and 4.1

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
NSString * v = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] substringToIndex:0];
```

more reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: check this post it has good answer http://www.techpaa.com/2012/11/best-way-checking-iphone-ios-version.html