# iphone: run application from iOS 4.2 on iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a problem. I develop a application, this app run successfully on iOS 4.2. Now I would like to run it on iOS 3.2, but the application crash before it load. Because of this line of code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

I understand that UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification is not available for iOS 3.2. But when I use:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_4_0
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadDataAfterEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
#endif
```

The application still run in that line of code and cause crash again. I don't know what should I do to let 3.2 does not run that line of code.

Thank you very much

Comment: your #ifdef is evaluated at compile time not runtime. If you link your app against ios 4.2 sdk the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post. Probably better to do it like this or something similar.

[How to detect current iOS is 4.1 or 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212534/how-to-detect-current-ios-is-4-1-or-4-2)

Comment: Thank you. But I can not use NSClassFromString because this is the notification: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification is only available for iOS 4 and later.

Answer (score 1):

use this

//    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000

```
  NSLog( @"After Version 4.0" ); 
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadDataAfterEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

//  #else

//  #endif