# Execute function when iOS version < 4.*

Tags: iphone, ios

how i can exectute a function if the iOS version is above 4.* in a if statement?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check iPhone iOS Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, take a look at weak linking of classes and methods in Apple's documentation — http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html they provide explicit instructions how to do support of multiple iOS'es in the same build. host answer from this big Apple's documentation:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController instancesRespondToSelector:
              @selector (availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice:)]) {
    // Method is available for use.
    // Your code can check if video capture is available and,
    // if it is, offer that option.
} else {
    // Method is not available.
    // Alternate code to use only still image capture.
}
```

Less flexible ways can be done on checking exact match of iOS by use of following code:

```
NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

You can do breakdown of osVersion to components and analyze them separately as numbers.

Cases when you class is not available for some particular iOS type is more complex and it is better to review a link to the document provided above.

Comment: It'a a good way but I search for something like if(OS_VERSION < 4){}

Comment: In the same documentation you can find an example with NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]; It should do what you need.

Comment: Just curious if it is works for you, could you mark my answer as the answer? :)