# Identify device's iOS version dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

I'm building an app that has an SMS composer (which isn't available in 3.0).
How can I find the underlying device's OS version dynamically and make the SMS option available, and if not disable the function?

Comment: It's always a bit fragile to determine a services availability by associating it with the version that it happened to be enabled in.  In the future if there's any variance in when that service is available, the code will start breaking.  I don't know much about SMS composer but if there's a programmatic way to determine whether the service is available, that would be better than a version check where it happened to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use `NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController")` to see if the class is available.

(Caveat: You couldn't check for `UIGestureRecognizer` this way because Apple used private class with the same name. Same could be true for `MFMessageComposeViewController`.)

Comment: this is along the lines of my comment above - switch on the capability  - not an incidental piece of related data.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the piece of code which will give you all the info about device

```
NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
    NSLog(@"name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
    NSLog(@"systemName: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]);
    NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
    NSLog(@"model: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
    NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]);
```

you can get here the version number.

But i will suggest you to go with checking that the phone supports mail composer,sms or not
like

Class messageClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));

```
if (messageClass != nil) {          
    // Check whether the current device is configured for sending SMS messages
    if ([messageClass canSendText])
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *msgpicker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        msgpicker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        msgpicker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.productInfoArray valueForKey:@"Phone"]]; // your recipient number or self for testing
        msgpicker.body = @"test from OS4";
        NSLog(@"chat view array  %@",[self.productInfoArray valueForKey:@"Phone"]);
        [self presentModalViewController:msgpicker animated:YES];
        [msgpicker release];
        NSLog(@"SMS fired");


    }
    else {      NSLog(@"chat view array  %@",[self.productInfoArray valueForKey:@"Phone"]);
        NSLog(@"Device not configured to send SMS.") ;
        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Status" message:@"Device not configured to send SMS." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
}
```

This will help to resolve your problem.
Happy Coding
Cheers................

Answer (score 4):

The UIDevice class has a systemVersion property you can use to get the OS version. This'll return the version value such as 3.1 or 4.2. Guess you can use this to determine access to your SMS functionality.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *systemVersion
```

Check out the reference for more info >
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html