# How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to check if the user is running the app on iOS less than 5.0 and display a label in the app.

How do I detect which iOS is running on user's device programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: This link might help : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/check-device-os-version.html

Answer (score 692, accepted):

**Best current version**, without need to deal with numeric search within NSString is to define `macros` (See original answer: [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/492624))

Those macros do exist in github, see: https://github.com/carlj/CJAMacros/blob/master/CJAMacros/CJAMacros.h

Like this:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

and use them like this:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"5.0")) {
    // code here
}

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    // code here
}
```

---

## Outdated version below

to get OS version:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

returns string, which can be turned into int/float via

```
-[NSString floatValue]
-[NSString intValue]
```

like this

> Both values (floatValue, intValue) will be stripped due to its type, 5.0.1 will become 5.0 or 5 (float or int), for comparing precisely, you will have to separate it to array of INTs
>      check accepted answer here: [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339787/492624)

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int ver_int = [ver intValue];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
```

and compare like this

```
NSLog(@"System Version is %@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
if (ver_float < 5.0) return false;
```

**For Swift 4.0 syntax**

below example is just checking if the device is of `iOS11` or greater version.

```
let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
if systemVersion.cgFloatValue >= 11.0 {
    //"for ios 11"
  }
else{
   //"ios below 11")
  }
```

Comment: Beware, as the float value of 5.0.1 is 5

Comment: @Michael thanks for notice, I've added link to relevant answer

Comment: this is not best way try this http://www.techpaa.com/2012/11/best-way-checking-iphone-ios-version.html

Comment: @jeeva thanks for pointing that out, I've added macros to top of my answer.

Comment: why is the `systemVersion` method "outdated"? According to Apple docs it isn't being deprecated, so for some other reason?

Comment: @SpencerWilliams because it doesn't handle well minor versions, it's sufficient if you need to recognize 5 from 6, but not 5.0.1 from 5.1.0

Comment: Hi, is this tested to work with iOS 7? Thanks.

Comment: @brain56 with all catches it has (see the original linked answer thread) yes, it works under iOS7

Comment: Thanks. I also had the opportunity to try it out, and I can confirm that **the solution works for iOS 7.**

Comment: Beware - this is correct, but relatively slow. I just found some code based on this answer as the bottom of the heaviest trace in Instruments, it was being called from scrollViewDidScroll: - obviously that can be written a different way but it hadn't been.

Comment: @AdamEberbach I'd suppose private final boolean field, initialized once if this is used in some often called logic. Or have you found out how to do it more efficiently?

Comment: NSNumericSearch will ignore decimal places, which means that something like 6.3 will equate to greater than 6.10. This also breaks if the system were to ever return 6.1.2 or something with more digits (it would get treated as value "612" with NSNumericSearch).

Answer (score 262):

### Update

From iOS 8 we can use the new `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion` method on `NSProcessInfo`

```
   NSOperatingSystemVersion ios8_0_1 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){8, 0, 1};
   if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:ios8_0_1]) {
      // iOS 8.0.1 and above logic
   } else {
      // iOS 8.0.0 and below logic
   }
```

Beware that this will crash on iOS 7, as the API didn't exist prior to iOS 8. If you're supporting iOS 7 and below, you can safely perform the check with

```
if ([NSProcessInfo instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:)]) {
  // conditionally check for any version >= iOS 8 using 'isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion'
} else {
  // we're on iOS 7 or below
}
```

---

### Original answer iOS < 8

For the sake of completeness, here's an alternative approach proposed by Apple itself in the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1), which involves checking the Foundation Framework version.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

Comment: This is currently the best answer and should be at the top.

Comment: Kinda bothers me that there MIGHT be a 6.2 release, then loads of code would break. But yea, recommended by Apple...

Comment: @NiklasBerglund agreed, even though a 6.2 is highly unlikely, as Apple itself recommends this method.

Comment: Beware, the constants for 6.1 and 6.0 have same value according to this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990900/nsfoundationversionnumber-and-ios-versions#comment29919228_19990991

Comment: Apparently Apple has yet to include NSFoundationVersionNumbers for 7, or 7.1. So I guess don't go with this method.

Comment: Be aware that calling `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion` will trigger an unrecognized selector sent to instance exception on iOS 7 and below.

Comment: @ecd1591, true. My answer starts with "from iOS8", but I could make it more explicit. Will do it later

Answer (score 23):

I know I am too late to answer this question. I am not sure does my method still working on low iOS versions (< 5.0):

```
NSString *platform = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].model: %@",platform);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].description: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].description);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].name: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].name);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName);
```

You can get these results:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].model: iPhone
[UIDevice currentDevice].description: <UIDevice: 0x1cd75c70>
[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel: iPhone
[UIDevice currentDevice].name: Someones-iPhone002
[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion: 6.1.3
[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName: iPhone OS
```

Answer (score 15):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

Answer (score 14):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];`

or check the version like

You can get the below Macros from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8042056/112705).

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(IOS_VERSION_3_2_0))      
{

        UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cs_lines_back.png"]] autorelease];
        theTableView.backgroundView = background;

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The macro you've used in defined in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8042056/112705

Answer (score 9):

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]
```

Comment: The easiest approach. In Swift (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue

Comment: it also worked in my case too. very simple to use.

Comment: //Greater than 10.0f----
 if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 10.0f){
}

Comment: won't work for OS like 6.0.7 (whose floatValue will be 7) the double decimal-point in the version-string may break 'floatValue' on version-strings.

Answer (score 5):

Marek Sebera's is great most of the time, but if you're like me and find that you need to check the iOS version frequently, you don't want to constantly run a macro in memory because you'll experience a very slight slowdown, especially on older devices.

Instead, you want to compute the iOS version as a float once and store it somewhere. In my case, I have a `GlobalVariables` singleton class that I use to check the iOS version in my code using code like this:

```
if ([GlobalVariables sharedVariables].iOSVersion >= 6.0f) {
    // do something if iOS is 6.0 or greater
}
```

To enable this functionality in your app, use this code (for iOS 5+ using ARC):

**GlobalVariables.h**:

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat iOSVersion;

    + (GlobalVariables *)sharedVariables;

@end
```

**GlobalVariables.m**:

```
@implementation GlobalVariables

@synthesize iOSVersion;

+ (GlobalVariables *)sharedVariables {
    // set up the global variables as a static object
    static GlobalVariables *globalVariables = nil;
    // check if global variables exist
    if (globalVariables == nil) {
        // if no, create the global variables class
        globalVariables = [[GlobalVariables alloc] init];
        // get system version
        NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        // separate system version by periods
        NSArray *systemVersionComponents = [systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        // set ios version
        globalVariables.iOSVersion = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01d.%02d%02d", \
                                       systemVersionComponents.count < 1 ? 0 : \
                                       [[systemVersionComponents objectAtIndex:0] integerValue], \
                                       systemVersionComponents.count < 2 ? 0 : \
                                       [[systemVersionComponents objectAtIndex:1] integerValue], \
                                       systemVersionComponents.count < 3 ? 0 : \
                                       [[systemVersionComponents objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] \
                                       ] floatValue];
    }
    // return singleton instance
    return globalVariables;
}

@end
```

Now you're able to easily check the iOS version without running macros constantly. Note in particular how I converted the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` NSString to a CGFloat that is constantly accessible without using any of the improper methods many have already pointed out on this page. My approach assumes the version string is in the format n.nn.nn (allowing for later bits to be missing) and works for iOS5+. In testing, this approach runs much faster than constantly running the macro.

Hope this helps anyone experiencing the issue I had!

Answer (score 4):

In MonoTouch:

To get the Major version use:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[0]
```

For minor version use:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get more specific version number information with major and minor versions separated:

```
NSString* versionString = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
NSArray* vN = [versionString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

The array `vN` will contain the major and minor versions as strings, but if you want to do comparisons, version numbers should be stored *as numbers* (ints). You can add this code to store them in the C-array* `versionNumbers`:

```
int versionNumbers[vN.count];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(versionNumbers)/sizeof(versionNumbers[0]); i++)
    versionNumbers[i] = [[vN objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
```

* C-arrays used here for more concise syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A simple check for iOS version less than 5 (all versions):

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] < 5){
        // do something
};
```

Comment: The system version is not an integer value.

Comment: this is too worst try this http://www.techpaa.com/2012/11/best-way-checking-iphone-ios-version.html