# How to detect an iOS version?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

We have a site which has a registration form. In this form we have a file upload button. As you already know when someone access our site via iOS devices they can't upload a file because iOS doesn't support file upload via safari. Now we found out iOS6 enables users to upload a photo via safari. Now the question is we don't know how many people will update to iOS6. So how can we detect which version of iOS a visitor is running and then show them a warning or a popup message ?

We want to detect if the site is accessed by iOS5.1 or less and show a popup message saying "Your software version does not support file upload. Please update to iOS 6 or download our app to upload your image"

Any help ? thank you.

Comment: You could check their user agent string. While it isn't fool proof since it can be easily spoofed, it will give you the OS version of the iOS safari version which would help determine the version of the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/05/check-the-ios-version-with-javascript/

There is a tutorial there, it was the most recent i could find (may 2012) as i know many methods dont work on newer IOS, worth a shot though! :)

Comment: No problems :) Let me know if it works for you!