# Detect iOS version in runtime

Tags: ios6, social-framework

I'm currently writing an app that uses Facebook integration built into iOS 6.
Now in order to do that, I need to

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

How do I ensure that the device can actually run the code and won't crash (check if it's iOS 6 or iOS 5.1 and then performing the right code, because I support iOS 5.1<= )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

Comment: @harrym17 Use that for the actually implementation, then in your project summary tab change the social framework from required to optional.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")){
//Use social framework
}else{
//other option
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you! This should work better than the marked answer, I will confirm and mark

Comment: Won't work unless you define it somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on