# Is it ok the below method to decide to use auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

```
(BOOL)isSupportAutoLayOut
{
    int version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion substringToIndex:1] intValue];
    if(version == 6)
    {
       return YES;
    }
    return NO;
 }
```

I want to support iOS 5 and iOS 6 system, on iPhone and iPad.

Does it have bug?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7848772/1271826 for determining iOS version. And, BTW, if you were checking for iOS versions, you want to check for iOS greater than or equal to 6.0 or less than 6.0, _not_ equal to 6.0. But the correct solution is that if your app is supporting iOS versions earlier than 6.0, then turn off auto layout altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
-(BOOL)isSupportAutoLayOut
{
    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion] floatValue];
    if(version >= 6.0)
    {
       return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy for iOS 5, you cannot use Autolayout. If you do, you'll get an exception saying device that doesn't support the new `NSLayoutConstraint` class in OS versions before iOS 6.

There is no way to support autolayout conditionally like you are asking.

However, it <s>may be</s> **is** possible to load from the code, a different storyboard or nib (.xib) file that is built using autolayout based on the conditional check for iOS 6 (<s>someone has to confirm this</s> I tried it, its working).