# What iOS version should I target my next iPhone app (considering facebook integration)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5, ios6

The reason for asking this question is facebook support that I want to provide.
Since there are crucial differences between iOS 6 and 5, I am confused.

1 - If I support only 5, I am losing serious user base, right? Does anyone has any country-wise analytics as to how many use which OS?

2 - If I support only 6, what all testing would I require? Do I need iOS 6 device or simulator is fine as far as facebook is concerned?

Comment: You can customize base target and deployment target.

Comment: Not sure why this question is voted for closing. I see many questions around like this. It would be fruitful if proper reason is cited for downvoting.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, could you emphasize more about it? I am doing facebook integration for the first time so not sure about what you mean.

Comment: Even I am new to ios, i worked for mac os. There we do like this: Set the Base SDK to Current version of Mac (ex. 10.7)
Set the Deployment SDK to older version (ex.1.4).   If similar thing can be done in ios.

Comment: You mean maintain 2 xcode projects targetting different iOS? I doubt if that would not lead me to different set of issues.

Comment: No in the same project, base sdk and deployment sdk. Base sdk says that you are using new methods, and deployment make it backward compatible.

Comment: but backward compatibility here means that on iOS6 he can use new Facebook methods and on 5 all that classes will be just `nil` - it will just not crash, but it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know any page that publish country-wise stats, but for example [here](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) you can find stats from one developer and they are similar to stats I have access to (sorry, but I cannot publish it) - anyway you'll loose around 20%-25% of audience when you'll support only iOS6.
2. You should always test on device before releasing - mostly app is behaving same on simulator, but not always. IMO one should even test on more devices (like iPhone3GS, iPhone4, iPhone5 etc.), but of course it is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use latest Facebook api for ios 6.0 and set to target ios 6.0 for your users.I think so as apple always insists their users to update their os and it's not permitting to downgrade the os.So if you look into the users then also find maximum users use the latest os. I think you should go for ios 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You check the version of the phone and based on the version then you wright the code in if-else statements. By this way you will support both iOS 5 and 6. as far as testing is concerned you will need a simulator or a device to check your app.[Here is a link by which you will detect the device os version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)