# Internal name of 5th generation iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

What is Apple's internal name for the 5th generation iPod Touch?

I can see the internal names of the iPhones from [iphonewiki.com](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IPhone). For example the iPhone 4S has the internal name "iPhone4,1". However I can't find any info on that site or from searching about the internal names of the iPod Touch devices.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're wanting to use the model name?  If you're targeting specific features you would be much better using the systemVersion and using a macro like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on

Comment: @JamieChapman Yes it's for analytics, not for specific features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's the iPod5,1

Source: http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iPod5,1