# How to execute a block of code in IOS7 not in IOS6?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uistatusbar

Hi In past I had developed one application which supports IOS6.Now the time came to support the same app for IOS7 also. For supporting the app for IOS6 & IOS7 I increased the `Y` value of each and every component by `20 pixels`.

Here I am getting the OS version by using`[[[UIDevice CurrentDevice]SystemVersion] floatvalue];` method.Based on that OS version I am changing the `rect` values for each and every component.

For handling the `StatusbarStyle` I am using the following methods in IOS7

```
 1. [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
 2.-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle;
```

These methods are working fine in IOS7, But if I install the app in IOS6 the app is crashing due to the above two methods.

So now my requirement is I have to hide or not execute IOS7 related methods or changes in IOS6 Device.With the help of this Implementation I hope I can resolve the issue.

Even I used few methods to resolve this crash issue.The methods which I used are

```
1. #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED== 70000
2.#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED==70000
```

Here while creating the ipa file deployment Target Which I had set is 6.0. Because I have to support IOS6 & IOS7.

So please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you put compile time error and also attach code that you test with condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

Answer (score 7):

use `NSFoundationVersionNumber` condition for doing this [Supporting iOS 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)

[image]

> If you need to load different resources for different app versions—and you currently identify a storyboard or XIB file in your **Info.plist** file—
>
> you can use the version of the `Foundation framework` to determine the current system version and load the appropriate resource in [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:). The code below shows how to check the Foundation framework version:

```
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier

    } else {

    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later

    }
```

Take a look the best answer of the same thing that you want

[iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 default style in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style)

Comment: Hi nitin Thanks a lot for your quick response.Still I am getting the error while compiling the code in IOS6.Error : Use of undeclared identifier "NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0"   and No visible @interface for "MainViewcontroller" declares the selector 'setNeedsStatusbarAppearanceUpdate'.

Comment: its 6.1 not 6.0 my frnd

Comment: please DO NOT use `floatValue` since it may lead to unexpected behaviors. For instance `[@"7.0.1" floatValue] < [@"7.0.2" floatValue]` => NO

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for this condition :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
} else {
    // iOS 6
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil thanks for your reply.Still I am getting the error.So please let me know any other way if you can.