# Add top layout guide in NIB file (XIB)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, autolayout

How can I add top layout guide in NIB file or how can I specify space from the top navigation bar and status bar so that it does not create problem between ios 6 and iOS 7?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7

Comment: I use an alternative way. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26397943/1021628

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this by by implementing new property called edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7 SDK

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
      if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
         self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

or

If you are using navigation bar  and xcode5 then..

In Interface Builder,select view controller, and then navigate to the attributes inspector. In "Extend Edges". check Under Top Bars

i have solved my problem from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Comment: Technically, you are accessing `setEdgesForExtendedLayout:` so you are kinda checking for response from the wrong method. But that's just nitpicking.

Comment: This doesn't help, because I have a background that I want to be visible through a transparent navigation bar. `edgesForExtendedLayout` pushes everything down.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to write this condition for that

```
 float SystemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
  if(SystemVersion<7.0f)
   {
     //Currently your app is running in IOS6 or older version. So you need not 
             to do anything.
   }
  else
   {
     // Currently your app is running in IOS7.
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

I am doing it programmatically.
because you have to check both the frame sizes for ios 7 and others.
because for status bar you have to manage 20 pixel in IOS 7 and other.
so, just put View in XIB as you want in any IOS and for other you can manage by this...

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
   NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
                NSLog(@"Ios7 resize the frame");

            }
            else
            {


            }

}

        if(result.height == 568)
        {
  NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
                NSLog(@"Ios7 resize the frame");


            }
            else
            {


            }
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: The problem with this code is that it is highly dependent on the screen size. These kind of things tend to change often!