# Different UI element types for iOS6/iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, interface-builder

I've got an app which I'm porting to iOS7, but I've stumbled across a problem in which the old app is using a grouped UITableView, and this looks wrong in iOS7. Changing it to an ungrouped table makes the iOS7 version look okay, but the iOS6 version doesn't quite look right. There seems to be no way of changing the grouped/ungrouped setting for the table at runtime, so I'm wondering if there's a way in interface builder (or in code) to use a different setting for that option depending on the OS version. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: It is certainly possible in code. Pass the proper style when creating the table based on the iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

Not from the interfaz builder, but yes from the code.

Just check the version of the iOS:

[How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

And then go to the line when you create the table, and change the style of it;

```
myTableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]
```

Or

```
myTableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the UITableView is in a Nib at the moment, so the `[UITableViewController alloc]` is never called from code. Is there a particular function I could put this call to override the way the view is loaded from the Nib?

Comment: The style of the table cannot be modified after the table is allocated, sorry. If the table view is in a nib, it will be loaded from there.