# NSFoundationVersionNumber and iOS Versions

Tags: ios, version

Well, my questions is really simple i guess.

I use NSFoundationVersionNumber to check the version of my app , and make it both compatible with iOS6 and iOS7 .

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 ){
//Here goes the code for iOS 7 
}

else if (NSFoundationVersionNumber == NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
//Here goes the code for iOS 6.1
}
```

Well,as far as i know, Apple has released 6.1.X versions.So, using the second "else-if" statement, versions 6.1.X are excluded from the list of compatible versions i make?If yes is the answer, then how can i determine ,if the device is running on 6.1.X versions?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `NSFoundationVersionNumber == NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` is true, then the device has 6.1.X.

When `NSFoundationVersionNumber == NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0` is true, the device has 6.0.X.

When `NSFoundationVersionNumber < NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0` is true, the device has 5.1.X and below.

When `NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` is true, the device has 7.0 and above.

Comment: So you tell me that NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 ,includes iOS 6.1.X versions? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, all versions are included. If you want to know precisely which, you will have to drill down `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion`.

Comment: That's not 100% true. 6_0 and 6_1 have the same foundation number (993.00 found in NSObjCRuntime.h). So for < NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 the device is 5.1 and below. Small point.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate, foundation versions for 6_0 and 6_1 are now different (992 & 993 respectively).

Comment: And if your device runs OS X 10.9.5, NSFoundationVersionNumber10_9_2 is below the real NSFoundation version and you're out of licl. Still not getting it

Comment: @Julian Sounds like a bug in OS X SDK. Open a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @LeoNatan There's just no `#define` for 10.9.5 in the SDK. I solved it by `floor`ing the version, because I'm not interested in the lower version.

Comment: @Julian Still, if Apple changed the foundation version, they should have a macro for each version. Still worth a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

apple forgot to provide NSFoundationVersionNumber constants for iOS 7, 10.8 and 10.9, but you can get the numbers by NSLogging out your NSFoundationVersionNumer (which gives you the NSFoundationVersionNumber of your current OS)

Comment: `NSLog("%.4f", NSFoundationVersionNumber)` is really a good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 8, Apple now provides the `NSOperatingSystemVersion` struct in [NSProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSProcessInfo/operatingSystemVersion)

You can use it with the `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:`, or just check the 3 fields to exactly know which system version is running your app.

Comment: This is definitely helpful. If you are supporting iOS7 and 8, however, you'll need to use a combination of NSFoundationVersionNumber and respondsToSelector for `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion` since that method is "Available in iOS 8.0 and later."