# Detects iOS 7.1 version

Tags: ios, ios7, ios7.1

I use this code

```
#define IS_IOS7 (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
```

To find if the app is running on iOS7.
But I now need to know if it runs on iOS7.1 but there isn't any `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0` and `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1`

I know the definition of

```
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1  993.00
```

So maybe I can compare with a number higher than 993 but I don't know.
Someone gets a safe and reliable solution ?

Comment: Looks like 7.1 is 1047.25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, and you can easily find them in several answers here on SO. Here are some:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

Slightly more complex, with test:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // iOS7...
}
```

You can add a more complete way to test for version like this:

```
/*
 *  System Versioning Preprocessor Macros
 */ 

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

/*
 *  Usage
 */ 

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"4.0")) {
    ...
}

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"3.1.1")) {
    ...
}
```

Sources:

[How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version)

[How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

Comment: It is good, but it works slower, than NSFoundationVerstionNumber.

Comment: @Dzmitry What is slower? I proposed 3 methods, where NSFoundationVersionNumber is the second...

Comment: Version at number 3 works slower than version at number 2. I checked it.

Comment: Yes, probably. But it's more fine-grained if you need that. Version 2 is probably the best for most cases. Thanks for sharing your results, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
 float fOSVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
     if(fOSVersion>7.0)//if it is greater than 7.0
     {
          //do your stuff here          
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this marco

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

And you can check version like this

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.1")){
   //do something
}
```