# Check OS version in Swift?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I'm trying to check system information in Swift. I figured out, that it could be achieved by code:

```
var sysData:CMutablePointer<utsname> = nil
let retVal:CInt = uname(sysData)
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. What should be sysData's initial value? This example gives -1 in retVal probably because sysData is nil.
2. How can I read information from sysData?

Answer (score 514, accepted):

For iOS, try:

```
var systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

For OS X, try:

```
var systemVersion = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion
```

If you just want to check if the users is running at least a specific version, you can also use the following Swift 2 feature which works on iOS and OS X:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    // use the feature only available in iOS 9
    // for ex. UIStackView
} else {
    // or use some work around
}
```

*BUT it is not recommended to check the OS version. It is better to check if the feature you want to use is available on the device than comparing version numbers.*
For iOS, as mentioned above, you should check if it responds to a selector; 
eg.:

```
if (self.respondsToSelector(Selector("showViewController"))) {
    self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
} else {
    // some work around
}
```

Comment: While this is correct for objective c there is a much nicer way of doing it in swift. Outlined here... https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking

Comment: One use I can see to checking the OS version directly (as opposed to checking for specific capabilities) is to gather data about the OS version distribution among your users, to determine your lowest deployment target.

Answer (score 127):

**Update:**
Now you should use new *availability checking* introduced with Swift 2:
e.g. To check for iOS 9.0 or later use can this:

```swift
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  // use UIStackView
} else {
  // show sad face emoji
}
```

or can be used with whole method or class

```swift
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func useStackView() {
    // use UIStackView
}
```

or with guard

```swift
guard #available(iOS 14, *) else {
    return
}
```

For more info see [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking).

**UPDATE:**
based on Allison's comment I have updated the answer, check is still runtime, but compiler can know in advance & can show better error or suggestion while you are working on it.

**Other ways to check:**

if you don't want exact version but want to check iOS 9,10 or 11 using if:

```
let floatVersion = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
```

**EDIT:**
Just found another way to achieve this:

```
let iOS8 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
let iOS7 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
```

Comment: Just a small correction: `#available` is NOT a compile time check—the same binary is distributed and runs on all devices regardless of version. This DOES have a runtime performance penalty and so you may want to avoid any of this in performance critical code.

Comment: @Allison thanks for suggesting the correction, just updated the answer.

Answer (score 65):

## Swift 5

We dont need to create extension since `ProcessInfo` gives us the version info. You can see sample code for iOS as below.

```
let os = ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion

switch (os.majorVersion, os.minorVersion, os.patchVersion) {
case (let x, _, _) where x < 8:
    print("iOS < 8.0.0")

case (8, 0, _):
    print("iOS >= 8.0.0, < 8.1.0")

case (8, _, _):
    print("iOS >= 8.1.0, < 9.0")

case (9, _, _):
    print("iOS >= 9.0.0")

default:
    print("iOS >= 10.0.0")
}
```

Reference: http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/

Comment: most useful answer. thanks

Answer (score 55):

I made helper functions that were transferred from the below link into swift:

[How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

```
func SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}
```

It can be used like so:

```
SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO("7.0")
```

### Swift 4.2

```swift
func SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) == .orderedSame
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) != .orderedAscending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) != .orderedDescending
}
```

Answer (score 23):

## Swift 5

```
func run() {
    let version = OperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 13, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isOperatingSystemAtLeast(version) {
        runNewCode()
    } else {
        runLegacyCode()
    }
}

func runNewCode() {
    guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    // do new stuff
}

func runLegacyCode() {
    // do old stuff
}
```

Comment: why in runNewCode is #available(iOS 11.0, *) needed?

Comment: @IllyaKrit The `#available(...)` block stops the compiler from displaying errors for code within that is not supported in versions older than provided.

Answer (score 16):

I made this, for simple use, **created an `IOSVersion.swift` file and added this code :**

```
import UIKit

enum IOSVersion {
    static func SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(version: NSString) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
    }
    
    static func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(version: NSString) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version as String,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
    
    static func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: NSString) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version as String,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    
    static func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: NSString) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version as String,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    
    static func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: NSString) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version as String,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
}
```

**USE :**

```
IOSVersion.SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO("8.0")
IOSVersion.SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN("8.0")
```

**Thanks @KVISH**

Edit Swift 2 :

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    //  
} else {
    // 
}
```

Comment: Is that singleton? or just class functions on IOSVersion? wouldn't a singleton be  `static let shared = IOSVersion`

Comment: @CharltonProvatas old post updated. (sentence error.)

Answer (score 15):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Links

[OperatingSystemVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operatingsystemversion)

### Solution

```
extension OperatingSystemVersion {
    func getFullVersion(separator: String = ".") -> String {
        return "\(majorVersion)\(separator)\(minorVersion)\(separator)\(patchVersion)"
    }
}

let os = ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion
print(os.majorVersion)          // 12
print(os.minorVersion)          // 2
print(os.patchVersion)          // 0
print(os.getFullVersion())      // 12.2.0
```

Comment: Aren't there potential rounding problems when using `Double` for a version number, e.g. `10.0999` instead of `10.1`?

Comment: No. `var stringVersion = "10.0999"; print(stringVersion.toDouble!) // print 10.0999`, it will print `10.0999`

Answer (score 9):

If you're using **Swift 2** and you want to check the OS version to use a certain API, you can use new availability feature:

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    //iOS 8+ code here.
}
else {
    //Code for iOS 7 and older versions.
    //An important note: if you use #availability, Xcode will also 
    //check that you don't use anything that was introduced in iOS 8+
    //inside this `else` block. So, if you try to use UIAlertController
    //here, for instance, it won't compile. And it's great.
}
```

I wrote this answer because it is the first question in Google for the `swift 2 check system version` query.

Answer (score 7):

Update for Swift 3.0+

```
func SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) != ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) != ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
}
```

Comment: Can skip `ComparisonResult` to make it shorter.

Comment: Also, factoring `UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric)` out into a `func` can help code reading.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and the simplest way to check system version (and a lot of other versions) in Swift 2 and higher is:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { // check for iOS 9.0 and later

}
```

Also, with `#available` you can check versions of these:

```
iOS
iOSApplicationExtension
macOS
macOSApplicationExtension
watchOS
watchOSApplicationExtension
tvOS
tvOSApplicationExtension
swift
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
let iosVersion = NSString(string: Device.systemVersion).doubleValue

let iOS8 = iosVersion >= 8
let iOS7 = iosVersion >= 7 && iosVersion < 8
```

and check as

```
if(iOS8)
{

}
else 
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mattt Thompson shares a very handy way

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) {
case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
    println("iOS >= 8.0")
case .OrderedAscending:
    println("iOS < 8.0")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.x

```
func iOS_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: NSString.CompareOptions.numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame
}

func iOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: NSString.CompareOptions.numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
}

func iOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: NSString.CompareOptions.numeric) != ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

func iOS_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: NSString.CompareOptions.numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

func iOS_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: NSString.CompareOptions.numeric) != ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
}
```

Usage:

```
if iOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: "11.0") {
    //Do something!
}
```

<sub>P.S. KVISH answer translated to Swift 4.x with renaming the functions as I am specifically using this snippet for the iOS app.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Note: Available in iOS 8.0 and later. OS X v10.10 and later

```
var majorVersion: Int    { return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion.majorVersion }
var minorVersion: Int    { return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion.minorVersion }
var patchVersion: Int    { return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion.patchVersion }
var myOSVersion:  String { return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersionString        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Matt Thompson's answer, here is a method with respective unit tests that works with **Swift** and **Objective-c** on **iOS 7 and above** (including **iOS 9** which no longer let's you check the **NSFoundationNumber**):

```
+ (BOOL) isAtLeastOSVersion:(NSString *)osVersion
{
    switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare:osVersion options:NSNumericSearch]) {
        case NSOrderedSame:
        case NSOrderedDescending:
            return YES;
        default:
            return NO;
    }
}
```

.

```
@interface ANFakeCurrDevice : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *systemVersion;
@end
@implementation ANFakeCurrDevice
@end


@implementation MyHelperClassUnitTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)test_isAtLeastOSVersion
{
    id deviceMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[UIDevice class]];
    ANFakeCurrDevice *fakeCurrDevice = [ANFakeCurrDevice new];
    fakeCurrDevice.systemVersion = @"99.9.9";
    [[[deviceMock stub] andReturn:fakeCurrDevice] currentDevice];
    XCTAssertTrue([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion isEqualToString:@"99.9.9"]);

    fakeCurrDevice.systemVersion = @"1.0.1";
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"1"]);
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"1.0"]);
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"1.0.1"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"1.0.2"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"1.1.0"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"2"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"2.0"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"2.0.0"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"2.0.1"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"2.1.0"]);


    fakeCurrDevice.systemVersion = @"8.4.0";
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"7.0.1"]);
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"8"]);
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"8.4"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"8.4.1"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"8.4.2"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"9.0"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"9.0.1"]);
    XCTAssertFalse([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"9.0.2"]);
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"8.4"] && ![ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"9.0"]);

    fakeCurrDevice.systemVersion = @"8.4.1";
    XCTAssertTrue([ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"8.4"] && ![ANConstants isAtLeastOSVersion:@"9.0"]);
}


@end
```

Comment: you do realize that the actual method is very short and compact and that I just added the unit test code for illustration and proof that it works, right?

Comment: I'm sorry that I failed to realize that it's XCTest at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

```
let osVersion = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion
let versionString = osVersion.majorVersion.description + "." + osVersion.minorVersion.description + "." + osVersion.patchVersion.description
print(versionString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to check WatchOS.

Swift

```
let watchOSVersion = WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
print("WatchOS version: \(watchOSVersion)")
```

Objective-C

```
NSString *watchOSVersion = [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSLog(@"WatchOS version: %@", watchOSVersion);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get current version of system and split it.
 So you can get major and minor version.**

```
let sys_version = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
let all_version = sys_version.components(separatedBy: ".")
print("Major version : \(all_version[0])")
print("Minor version : \(all_version[1])")
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of sample codes written here will get unexpected result with extra-zero versions. For example,

```
func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
return UIDevice.current.systemVersion.compare(version, options: .numeric) != ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}
```

This method won't return true with passed version "10.3.0" in iOS "10.3". This kind of result does not make sense and they must be regarded as same version. To get accurate comparison result, we must consider comparing all of number components in version string. Plus, providing global methods in all capital letters is not a good way to go. As version type we use in our SDK is a String, it's make sense that extending comparing functionality in String.

To compare system version, all of the following examples should work.

```
XCTAssertTrue(UIDevice.current.systemVersion.isVersion(lessThan: "99.0.0"))
XCTAssertTrue(UIDevice.current.systemVersion.isVersion(equalTo: UIDevice.current.systemVersion))
XCTAssertTrue(UIDevice.current.systemVersion.isVersion(greaterThan: "3.5.99"))
XCTAssertTrue(UIDevice.current.systemVersion.isVersion(lessThanOrEqualTo: "10.3.0.0.0.0.0.0"))
XCTAssertTrue(UIDevice.current.systemVersion.isVersion(greaterThanOrEqualTo: "10.3"))
```

You can check it out in my repository here
https://github.com/DragonCherry/VersionCompare