# Support multiple iOS SDK versions with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios10

In my code, I have the following extension for `NSManagedObject`:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let name = self.dynamicType.entityName()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(name, inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

Which was working as expected in Xcode 7 / iOS 9 SDK. However, iOS 10 SDK adds a method with the same signature:

```
/* Returns a new object, inserted into managedObjectContext. This method is only legal to call on subclasses of NSManagedObject that represent a single entity in the model.
 */
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public convenience init(context moc: NSManagedObjectContext)
```

Which makes the compiler unhappy: `Initializer 'init(context:)' with Objective-C selector 'initWithContext:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector`

Now, I would like to use the new iOS 10 init if it's available and keep using my extension if the application runs on devices with iOS 9.

Is there a nice way how to achieve this while limiting the changes in existing code? I would like to keep the signature of `init` in the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I'm concerned, you must change the signature of your `init` one way or another. It doesn't have to be a big change though:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let name = self.dynamicType.entityName()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(name, inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

I just removed the external parameter name of `context`. Now it doesn't conflict with the newly added one.

Then, you can just check the iOS version using the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/check-os-version-in-swift), and call the correct initializer!