# Swift 3 - @available only for ios 9 and not ios 10

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to see if this is possible. Looks like setting UICollectionViewFlowLayout's estimatedItemSize doesn't work very good in ios 9. It works perfectly fine ios 10. So i am thinking of implementing sizeForItemAt.. method only for ios 9. Is there anyway to do that using @available ?? Will be really helpful if someone can shed light.

Comment: **Swift 3 and 4** [Link to **exact solution** to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358077/7668778)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check OS version in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/check-os-version-in-swift)

Answer (score 13):

I wanted to execute code when the version is lower iOS 11, here's how I did it:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
  // This is probably empty
} else {
  // This code will only be executed if the version is < iOS 11
}
```

It's not the cleanest solution, but I couldn't find a better way and it does its job.

Answer (score 6):

Eh? Do as [docs say to do](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html):

```
@available(iOS, obsoleted: 10.0)
```

Or

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 9.0, obsoleted: 10.0)
```

Comment: I tried both the options, in both cases, it gets executed in ios 10 as well. Not sure why

Answer (score 3):

```
let systemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
println("iOS\(systemVersion)")

if systemVersion == 9.0 {
  //Do Something
}
```

You can use like below:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
private func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    logParklee.verbose("willPresentNotification")
}
```

Or

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    // use UIStackView
} else {
    // show sad face emoji
}
```

Or

```
guard #available(iOS 9, *) else {
    return
}
```

Or

```
@available(iOS 7, *)
func iOS7Work() {
    // do stuff

    if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        iOS8Work()
    }
}

@available(iOS 8, *)
func iOS8Work() {
    // do stuff
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        iOS9Work()
    }
}

@available(iOS 9, *)
func iOS9Work() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: As i said, I want the entire method to be run only on iOS 9 and not on iOS10. Your solution works the other way around.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Again. I want the entire func to be executed on iOS 9 and not on 10. Your version talks only about #available and and not @available. If you see my question, its about sizeForItemAt getting called or not.

Comment: @Kesava First code block seems to be perfect and will work only in iOS 9.

Comment: First block works if we are inside a func. I am talking about @available which is for the whole func. not for a piece of code. Please read the question fully.