# How to check if iOS has an update available?

Tags: ios, version

I am creating an application to inform the user if he has an update, I have already found how to recover the current version, but the problem here is how can I verify if the iPhone/iPad are already have the latest iOS update?

> PS: like in the lookout app

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no direct way to do such a check.

However, it might be achievable (as a workaround), by getting what's the latest released iOS version from an external resource. It could be something like Apple RSS feed -or a similar resource- and comparing it with the current device's iOS version, using *[systemVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620043-systemversion)*:

> The current version of the operating system.

as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505884/5501940).

For instance, you could request an API that might be built by your team to get what's the latest iOS version and resend it to your application to do the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'am trying to find something like what you said (a json response or rss feed) to can compare it with the version it got from device

Comment: Could you share it when you find it? we could make the question/answer more useful to the viewers :)

Comment: It's not this simple. Even if it's determined there is a newer version of iOS available, it doesn't mean the current device can be updated to it.