# In app rating for users with OS version below iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, skstorereviewcontroller

How would app users with iOS version lower than iOS 11 be able to rate an app?

Do I have to write conditional code something like this

```
if (iOS11) {
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
} else {
    //show custom review prompt and redirect to app store
}
```

Will Apple allow this or reject the app?
If Apple won't allow this then what should be done for other users?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check OS version in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/check-os-version-in-swift)

Comment: checking os version is expected if you support below I think 10.2 and below for thats controller (so check for at least 10.3 and above) - adding this wont get you rejected, not adding the check would let your app crash and then it would be rejected.

Comment: @JustinM The code posted by Dan is ObjectiveC.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version/3339787#3339787. You need to check for iOS 10.3 instead of iOS 11 since SKStoreReviewController was introduced in that version.

Comment: @JustinM thanks for the answer, but I am not worried of version checking but wants to know if it would be allowed by apple to redirect old version users to app store for accepting ratings?

Comment: @nathan Xcode 9 brings that functionality to objective-c. Being that Dan is using ios 11, I assume that is the case. Although the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Yeah, my point was about the different syntax in ObjC: `if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)) {}` instead of Swift's `if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {}`

Comment: @Dan I assume the requirement only applies to users who have updated to the necessary version, but you never really know with Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working and Tested Solution

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreReviewController")) {

            [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
        }
        else{
             //redirect user to AppStore
        }
```