# Swift - using #available inside Struct for initializing variable

Tags: swift, swift-structs

I need to initialize a variable depending on the OS version. I'm trying to use #available inside a `struct. I need to initialize a variable at the time of declaration.

Here is my code that I tried,

```
struct ColorConstants {

  static var os = 0
  #available(iOS 9, *)
  os = 9

  #available(iOS 10, *)
  os = 10
}
```

It gives me a build error:

> Expected declaration

[image: code error screenshot]

Comment: An `if` statement needs to be in a function.

Comment: You are right, but I will edit my question with some changes.

Comment: I need to initialize a variable depending on OS version

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Edited question for to be more clear

Comment: Yes, but why do you need this? You haven't provided any context.

Comment: If you think you need this `os` variable then you are probably doing some things incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're actually trying to do, so there are probably better approaches, but based very literally on what you're showing in your question, you could try something like this:

```
static var os: Int {
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        return 9
    }
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        return 10
    }

    return 0
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find the correct way of using #available inside a Struct for initializing a variable without any method as told in upper comments.

Comment: Your solution has worked for me, I will still try to edit my question for to be more clear

Comment: Yes you made it very clear that you're trying to use #available in a struct, but as I've said you have not explained what you're going to use this for. e.g. [there are other ways of getting the OS version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505884/1032372). The `#available` approach might not actually be what you want depending on your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but your solution will also work for so many other scenarios of coding when programmers will try use #available inside a Struct

Comment: Ok sure whatever have fun