# Get the iOS version of a device programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I want to get the iOS version of the devices which my app is installed on them .
Actually I think it is the SDK version of my app . 
How can I get that by code ?
Does it have any function or not ?
And also excuse me if I can't explain it good ☹️ .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/check-os-version-in-swift

Answer (score 27):

Use this func for **swift 4**,

**1. Get app version that is in the genral**

```
func getAppInfo()->String {
    let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
    let version = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
    let build = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
    return version + "(" + build + ")"
}
```

**2. Get app current name that is in general**

```
func getAppName()->String {
    let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
    return appName
}
```

**3. Get device iOS version in which app is running.**

```
func getOSInfo()->String {
    let os = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
    return String(os.majorVersion) + "." + String(os.minorVersion) + "." + String(os.patchVersion)
}
```

**Input**

```
    print("OS Version: \(getOSInfo())")
    print("App version: \(getAppInfo())")
    print("App Name: \(getAppName())")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: If you want the String: `ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersionString`

Answer (score 12):

Use the below code to get the version:

swift 4

```
let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

Objective c

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```