# How to check latest version of iOS in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can we check if the OS running on iPhone is the latest one. Is there any API for that?

The question is not to check the current version of iOS instead its for checking whether the current version of iOS is the latest or not

Comment: You can find a quite big discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/check-os-version-in-swift#24505884

Comment: this is not the same question. have you even read the question. For example, user is using iOS 14.6, so I want to know if its the latest version that he is using

Comment: AFAIK, there is not an API for this. You could use one of the techniques in the linked question to get the current iOS version, and check it against your own API. You would, of course, have to update your API with the latest/current version.

Comment: I'm curious why your app needs to know what the latest available version of iOS is. Also, what about older devices? Let's say the latest (non-beta) version of iOS is 17.3. What it the user is using an iOS device that can't run iOS 17. Do you want to know that the latest version is 17.3 or 16.7 (or whatever the device actually supports)?

Comment: We want to tell the user that their device is not updated so update it and it will be a bonus if that api can tell us the latest version that a device can support for example an older iphone 8 could support ios 14 or something etc

Answer (score 1):

An availability of the specific version iOS version can be checked with `@available`:

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    // Use iOS 11 APIs.
} else {
    // Alternative code for earlier versions of iOS.
}
```

More details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/marking_api_availability_in_objective-c

"The latest version" is a very relative concept, and you usually should use this macro to check if the specific frameworks/APIs are supported, no matter if their iOS version is the "latest".

Comment: this is not the answer. For example, user is using iOS 14.6, so I want to know if its the latest version that he is using