# How to check SwiftUI version

Tags: swiftui

I want to know my project use swiftUI 3 or swiftUI 4 .

env
xcode 13.2.1

i hav try to google for answer , and read the apple documentation, and look setting of project and settings of Xcode's preference.

Answer (score 6):

The SwiftUI version relates to the iOS version. You could verify the version using the available API

```swift
if #available(iOS 17, *) {
    print("SwiftUI 5.0")
} else if #available(iOS 16, *) {
    print("SwiftUI 4.0")
} else if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    print("SwiftUI 3.0")
} else if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    print("SwiftUI 2.0")
} else if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    print("SwiftUI 1.0")
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/check-os-version-in-swift) you can find some solutions here

Comment: does this work exactly like this for macOS as well?

Comment: @Cyril SwiftUI 1.0 was released with Catalina so you could test for `if #available(macOS 10.15, *)` or `if #available(macCatalyst 10.15, *)` and increase the versions accordingly, but I didn't test it

Comment: @Carsten Nice answer--this info is surprisingly hard to find online. You would think if you google "SwiftUI 3.0", the top link would be Apple's documentation giving a "what's new" list, but nothing like that. Did you find this info somewhere? Or you knew it based on recollection of the iOS releases?

Comment: @JamesToomey I just searched for "what's new in iOS x" and checked the documentation