# Is there anybody who could help me to convert Objective-C UIDevice+SystemVersion into Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, uidevice

I don't know how to convert the following Objective-C code into Swift as I have not worked with Objective-C before. How should I do it? If somebody has encountered something similar, any help of how the Objective-C code below would look like in Swift would be much appreciated.

```
// header (.h) file:

#import <UIKit / UIKit.h>

@interface UIDevice(SystemVersion)

  - BOOL systemVersionLessThan: (NSString *) target

@end
```

```
// implementation (.m) file

#import "UIDevice+SystemVersion.h"

@implementation UIDevice(SystemVersion)

  - BOOL systemVersionLessThan: (NSString *) target {
    [[self systemVersion] compare: target options: NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending
  }
```

I can't seem to get my head around of the right way to do this in Swift.
This more likely is way off it really should be.

```
import UIKit

extension UIDevice {
  func SystemVersion() {
    if systemVersionLessThan ->  {}
  }
}
```

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453654/1187415

Comment: Curious what you would use this for? You should probably be using `@available/#available`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal *translation* is

```
extension UIDevice {
    func systemVersionLessThan(_ target: String) -> Bool {
        systemVersion.compare(target, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
    }
}
```

You can also use

```
extension UIDevice {
    func systemVersionLessThan(_ target: String) -> Bool {
        systemVersion.localizedStandardCompare(target) == .orderedAscending
    }
}
```