How to read Apple Developer documentation for specific iOS version
How does one find correct examples of documentation when developing for a bit older iOS platform version? E.g. at the time I'm asking this, iOS 18 is out but I want an app that runs on iOS 16. The documentation for TabView (an iOS 13.0 feature) suggests using TabView like this:
// TabView is an iOS 13.0 feature, so fine
TabView {
    // Tab is an iOS 18 feature, so not available for iOS 16 app
    Tab("Received", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill") {
        ReceivedView()
    }
    .badge(2)
}

As TabView is clearly an iOS 13 feature, there must have been another way to use it before iOS 18 was out, but it doesn't seem very obvious how to limit Apple Developer documentation to only show features and examples that can be used e.g. in iOS 16.
I was looking for some switch or help for iOS version, but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to look into the older version of documentation?

If I understand your question correctly, you're worried about potential changes of objects, such as TabView, in different iOS version. The thing is that Xcode handles these changes when you export your application. So generally, there should be no problem if you use suitable (latest) version of Xcode and iOS SDK. If you want to do some specific changes based on iOS version in your app, take a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503001/

Well, I just want to know right now how to use TabView element in SwiftUI, but official documentation only provides examples for iOS 18. XCode already gives an error that Tab is only supported for iOS 18, but I'd like to see how to develop something for iOS16 (or even iOS 17, I guess plenty of people didn't upgrade their phones yet) without Googling for solution.

Google or ChatGPT, Apple official documentation is a bit of a miss-or-hit. Some of them have the new stuff without the older ones, some are still not updated and have the deprecated code, and some have both. My guess is that Apple has many internal teams and they all have different policies on official documentation. Anyway, this will not be a problem for 95% of the time (from my own experience)

Sure, Googling helps, but I imagined something like e.g. a version drop-down box in Python where one can get docs for whatever version they develop for. I've asked this question primarily to see if I'm just too stupid to read Apple's documentation or is it really missing such basic features.
