# Showing alert with iOS7, iOS8 both

Tags: ios

As `UIAlertController` is used for showing alert in iOS8.my app should be compatible with ios6, ios7 too.I think ios6,7 are still using `UIAlertView` for showing alert.
I want to show alert after checking for ios6,7,8 by different ways like for ios7 using `UIAlertView` and for ios8 using `UIAlertController`.I need objectiv-c code.

Please Help!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the class is available

```
if ([UIAlertController class]){
    // ios 8 or higher
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert title" message:@"Alert message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {
    // ios 7 or lower
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert title" message:@"Alert message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

}
```