# How to find out on which iOS will an app run?

Tags: ios, iphone, version-control

I'm a bit confused about this issue.....here goes:

I have an iPhone running iOS 8.4.
I have developed a paid app using Xcode 6.0 with support till iOS 8.0.
So what I want to know is, if I download this app (w/o paying!) on my iPhone, will it run?

Regards,
OM

Comment: Most likely it will run. Will it work perfectly? Probably since the app is done for 8.0. But not necessarily since Apple will break things in every single release.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on

Comment: Thanks guys....i tried running the app's build using Xcode 6.0 on my iPhone, but it immediately said: "The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted - your device may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode"...................so I guess it won't run then...