# How to support iOs 9 feature(s), while keeping iOs 8 support?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios9

Basically the question is in the title. I'm sure there's a way to ship your app to an earlier version of iOs (8 in this case), while still being able to use an exclusive feature of a newer OS version.
Example:
My app has a minimum support of iOs 8.3, and with the latest release of iOs 9, I wanna add support to force touch (which is only available in iOs 9), but in the same time, I want to be able to fix bugs and do UI improvements for example and ship the update to both versions.
Major apps do this, fb for example, so there MUST be a way, but I couldn't find it anywhere, I'm giving up :(

**EDIT**: is there a *neat* way to do it? without checking `respondsToSelector` and these kind of stuff? something like separate project? or maybe xcconfig files can do this trick? I'm just wondering.. because having an `if else` on every ios 9 targeted feature isn't really a good solution when you're talking about an enterprise/large app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift 2's availability feature should solve your problems. With availability, Swift builds in support for OS versioning and symbol availability testing.

First, set your deployment target in build settings to iOS 8.3 and your base SDK to Latest. If you use symbols (classes, methods, etc) in your project that are only available in operating systems newer than your deployment target (iOS 8.3), Xcode will display an error message with a fix-it on that line when you try to build and run your project.

See [Checking API Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID523) in the *Control Flow* chapter of *The Swift Programming Language* book.

An availability check looks like this:

```
if #available (iOS 9, *) {
    // use APIs only available on iOS 9 or later
} else {
    // do nothing, don't show feature in UI, etc
}
```

Those are the basics. In the second part of your question, what you're looking for is a way to handle API availability on a larger scale. To do this, you can use another feature of Swift 2's availability feature, the `@available` attribute. You can apply this attribute to any symbol definition–for example, a class–to mark that the definition of the symbol requires a certain minimum OS version.

Instead of using an availability check in every single place you use an iOS 9 API, you can just use the `@available` attribute on an entire class. Then you only need to use an availability check at the place you use that class. For example:

```
@available(iOS 9, *)
class MyAwesomeiOSNineFeature {
    var myCoolObject = UICooliOSNineThing()
    func doAwesomeStuff() {
        // lots of code that uses iOS 9 stuff, no availability check
    }

    func doOtherStuff() {
        // lots of code that uses iOS 9 stuff, no availability check
    }
}

// In another class that doesn't have an `@available` requirement:
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    let feature = MyAwesomeiOSNineFeature()
    feature.doAwesomeStuff()
} else {
    // don't show UI for new feature
}
```

Comment: yes, apparently there's no way around if else, maybe encapsulating them in factories and optionals of custom classes so the general code is readable without custom features, but the checking happens inside.
I think this answers my question, so, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

a device being on iOS 9 doesnt mean it has 3d touch, you should use the [forceTouchCapability](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITraitCollection/forceTouchCapability) property to determine if the device has 3d touch, and make certain parts of your code react appropriately

if you need to know which iOS version the device is running, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on) and you can use if-else statements to make your code react appropriately (like making sure the property actually exists on this devices OS version)

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't help because that property does not exist on iOS 8. He's asking how to handle when symbols don't exist, not how to test for specific features–the tests themselves are important in other ways, but don't exist on earlier versions of the platform.

Answer (score -1):

set the "iOS Deployment Target" in Build Settings to 8.3 and your base SDK to Latest iOS (iOS 9.0).

you can have iOS 9 code in iOS 8 supported classes, just make sure any iOS 9 only code is never executed on a iOS 8 device. you can use respondsToSelector: or [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] to help.