# How to specify availability only in a delegate (inheritance) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

My application is going to support PIP in AVPlayer after iOS 9 but I still want to keep my app working in iOS 7 and above. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730271/how-to-support-ios-9-features-while-keeping-ios-8-support) regarding with the availability check. But it seems not working for my case. For example:

My code:

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate
```

This works fine in iOS 9, but how to make it works in iOS 7 and above? I can't do this:

```
   @available(iOS 9.0, *)
   class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate
   @available(iOS 7.0, *)
   class PlayerViewController: UIViewController
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the delegate code into an extension:

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
}
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
extension PlayerViewController: AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate {
}
```