# Develop app for iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode

If I develop an app for iOS 9.1, my app will work in iOS 8?

I have this setup in Xcode (see image)
[Xcode setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZpAU.png)

Comment: Please read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Que :** If I develop an app for iOS 9.1, my app will work in iOS 8?

**Ans :** If you set 1Deployment Target1 8.0 it will work, if you set 1Deployment Target1 9.1 it will not.

You have set `Base SDK` in your application as your attached image says, base SDK is your current iOS version library which is used to develop your application. It should be latest always.

While `Deployment Target` decides on which iOS versions your application works. Following image depicts how to change Deployment Target of your application.
[image: Set Deployment Target in your project]

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set the Deployment Target to iOS 8.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank You. So, If I set the Deployment Target to iOS 8, the app will work in iOS 8, 9 & 9.1, am I right?

Comment: This is only the first step. You also need to take steps to ensure you don't use any iOS 9 APIs while running on an iOS 8 device.

Comment: Yes, you must not use any iOS 9 specific classes or calls unless you ensure that they exist at runtime. It should be pretty obvious if you test your app in iOS 8. If using Swift, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730271/how-to-support-ios-9-features-while-keeping-ios-8-support

Answer (score 0):

You need to ***set "Deployment target" to iOS 8.0*** in order to support iOS 8 onwards. What you have shown in the screenshot is ***"Base SDK"*** which is a different thing.