# How can I change the base SDK on xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod

I want to change the base SDK on xcode 4.2, how can I do this?

Comment: If your app relies heavily on new Classes and methods from ios5, it will not be fun.

Will it be worth it to make it run on the older devices? ie will the app still be useful with the ios5 features stripped out of it?

Comment: I just want to test it once on an ipod 4 with 4.2 and I don't want to do a software update and yes, it probably would be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give Base SDK as iOS 5.0, deployment target as OS version that you want to run (4.2?).

**Most important thing is you can't use any API's/ libraries introduced in iOS 5.0**. If you want to use them, make sure they are only called if running OS responds to them..If you are calling any methods which is not present in iOS 4.2, you have to check first whether they are available on running OS..[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version) question might help you there..[This](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) blog post might also helps..

Comment: I have already tried this and 4.2 doesn't come up as a selection. only 5.0 or latest 5.0