# How can I check if a feature is available on a specific iOS version?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, appearance

In my AppDelegate I am using the appearance proxy to make custom UI:

```
//Setup custom appearances
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This will crash in iOS4. How can I check if this feature is available on the iOS version they are running, so I can avoid the crash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check iPhone iOS Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't check the OS, check if the capability exists.

`if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {}`

Comment: Shocking. I don't see any harm in checking OS version. The mere presence of a symbol does not make its underlying implementation equal between OS releases.

Comment: Apple does not recommend checking the version. You should look for features you are interested in, as @joshua stated.

Comment: While I agree fundamentally (except in rare cases), I believe that recommending a different method is not a complete answer.  An exception case for me was a workaround for a frameworks bug in iOS 4 that caused issues in iOS 5, where the APIs were unchanged.  A complete answer answers the question, then recommends the better method.

Comment: Working around OS bugs is a whole different issue.

Comment: Actually ```- respondsToSelector``` is an instance method. For classes you should use ```class_respondsToSelector(Class c, SEL s);```

Comment: classes are objects, calling an instance method on the class like I did is perfectly valid, and will give the results expected.

Comment: instead of `[[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]` you can just do `[UINavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. The question was previously "How can I check if a user is on iOS4 or iOS5?" by the way.

Comment: People should validate the facts before down voting.