# coreImage iOS 4.3.3 crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

guys, I have iOS app, which running good on ios5.0, but on 4.3.3 it's crashing and writing this to console:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
  Referenced from: /Users/IvanTrufanov/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/99C63A08-CC3E-49B7-A27D-1352D61C7C4F/habr.app/habr
  Reason: image not found
```

Have you any ideas? What can be reason?

Comment: for first step, check that the image name you are using is having same text case @"image.png"/@"Image.png". this casing must match with the actual image name in your resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Image is only available with iOS 5.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Core Image is only available to iOS 5.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to find other solution.

Answer (score 1):

As others note CoreImage requires iOS 5+. But you can still use CoreImage in apps supporting iOS 4.3 and below by weak linking against the framework.

To do this go to your project's build phases, find the "CoreImage.framework" reference and change the optional/required flag to optional.

Of course the CoreImage API won't be available prior to iOS 5, so you'll want to check the OS version before making any framework calls. You might find the following macros handy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/82169