# dyld: Library not loaded reason: image not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have just discovered that my app doesn't run in 4.3 even though the deployment target is set to 4.3.

I get the following error, any ideas?

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage   Referenced
>   from: /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/E8046B99-C01A-4F62-A875-1261367763A5/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: May want to check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287165/82169

Comment: possible duplicate of [coreImage iOS 4.3.3 crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228961/coreimage-ios-4-3-3-crash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that CoreImage is avalaible in 4.3.2?

Check this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

"Core Image is an image processing technology built into Mac OS X v10.4 and iOS 5.0 ..."

Comment: I am getting the error but running 5.0. COuld it be caused by anything else?

Comment: I was able to run with CoreImage on 4.1 with CoreImage set as Optional rather than Required in the Frameworks section. HTH.

Answer (score 5):

In the target's build phases - > Link binaries with libraries set the relevant framework (CoreImage.framework in your case) to "Optional" instead of "Required".

Comment: yep, it's because of missing libs in device with iOS 5.x

Answer (score 2):

CoreImage is iOS 5 and above. You need to set the development target to iOS 5 and add CoreImage  - link binary with libraries (CoreImage Framework).