# How to change keyboard background color in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-keypad

I would like to know how to change the keyboard background color programmatically in iOS?
The background is normally grey but I have already seen black background (behind letters).

Comment: sorry about the close vote; I misread the question - edited for clarification.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For the dark background use:

```
mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

Read to find more information about [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits) (use `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` at iOS 7+).

Answer (score 38):

To change it globally, you can use appearance proxy in AppDelegate... I've tested it in iOS 8, Swift:

```
UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
```

Comment: This can also be used for setting the colour of the keyboard for swiftui

Answer (score 27):

In iOS 7, `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` is deprecated, so use this instead:

```
mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

If you need to support both earlier iOSes and iOS 7, and you've created the necessary macros (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/588253), you can use this:

```
mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0") ? UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert : UIKeyboardAppearanceDark);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer above, I was wondering if you'd happen to know why this won't compile when I'm building for a target of iOS 6 and also supporting iOS7?

Answer (score 10):

Updating to swift 3.0

`let textFieldAppearance = UITextField.appearance()
 textFieldAppearance.keyboardAppearance = .dark //.default//.light//.alert`

Comment: Is there a reason not to do just UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark ?

Comment: No, you can do this way too.

Comment: I know, I was asking if there's a reason you don't do it the short way?

Comment: `UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark` in AppDelegate will change the appearance globally. with this solution you can do it on specific text fields.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Interface Builder, you can set keyboard look in the Attributes Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Today just use `myTextField.keyboardAppearance = .dark`

Comment: Good to know and happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 4+: in the AppDelegate

```
UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

Comment: I need the same thing for UITextView but it doesn't exist.

Comment: @randomcontrol Did you try `textView.keyboardAppearance`? The property comes from `UITextInputTraits`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+ (TextView)**

```
 textView.keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Objectve-C

For Dark Keyboard

```
[UITextField appearance].keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

For Light keyboard

```
[UITextField appearance].keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceLight;
```

You can define this in AppDelegate to handle this globally.