# Change the color of the iPhone keyboard (working with Phonegap/Cordova)

Tags: iphone, cordova, colors, keyboard, cordova-2.0.0

As the title states: is it possible to change the keyboard color to black (some call it transparent?) when working with Phonegap/Cordova? I've googled a lot but I can't seem to find anything about it. So can it be done? Either with HTML5/jquery or in XCode?

A picture of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use a dark theme on the iOS Keyboard, you can [follow this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios).

You can add the Objective-C code to your PhoneGap project's `AppDelegate.m`

Comment: how would you apply this to all input elements in order for it to work with phonegap? see if you can solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889830/change-keyboard-bg-color-in-native-ios-app-with-phonegap-cordova-xcode