# Phonegap iOS app: change keyboard appearance to UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert (again)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, keyboard

A couple of months ago, I posted a question asking if and how phonegap users can alter the keyboard appearance to the dark alert ui keyboard (UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert) without targeting individual textfields. I did some extnsive reaearch myself and offered a bounty but yet the question remained unsolved.

[Alter keyboard appearance in native, phonegap/Cordova built iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889830/alter-keyboard-appearance-in-native-phonegap-cordova-built-ios-app)

As of today, I'm still struggling to get this resolved and simply over with. I do realize much probably hasen't happened since last time I bothered you with this question, however, two things have in fact changed which somewhat justifies this seemingly double post:

1. Phonegap has released version 2.1 which does some new stuff, perhaps this is possible now?
2. As my client expects me to solve this in any way possible, this time I would also like to ask you for an alternative approach. If it still can't be done, would it be possible to custom make a "keyboard" of my own? I know this of course is technically doable, but is it in any way a recommended approach that would be considered in at least some way smart and justified? As I said, my client pushes hard for this and is not in favor of rebuilding the app completely natively.

Conclusively, as of today is there any way to do this with phonegap / Cordova? If not, would you recommend me to custom make a keyboard using HTML CSS and JavaScript, bearing in mind this is a major comsern for my client? If so, are there any good plugins that I can use as a start? Please check out my old post (linked above) to see what has already been tested.

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Comment: I realize this is a long shot but would it perhaps be possible to via a plugin programmatically replace html textfields with native textfield and thereby target these textfields by their html ids?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but I came accross it looking for the same thing. Anyway, I have found a possible solution which would be to create a plugin for Cordova http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

It does require some native coding but would atleast avoid starting an app from scratch which has already been built in Cordova.