# How can I override the keyboad of iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, overriding, cydia

I want to change the color of the iPhone/iPad , as well as i know in cydia apps its possible in jailbreak device check this URL : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcnJ2YXLqtM
Please share your knowledge regrinding cydia apps,

Any help is greatly appreciated. Plz join hands.. !

Thanks in advance.,

Comment: Try checking out this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios

Comment: Thanks but just inform you i want to change the color of the keyboard for whole device not for particular application.

Comment: For the whole device, that is NOT allowed. Apple would never accept an app that modifies the whole devices keyboard. There is no documented code to do this anyways. Im not so sure how you can...

Comment: Ya i am aware about this , but i want to develop this app for jailbreak device and cydia