# How can I change iOS keyboard background to darker color i.e. to black?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

I will have an App in App Store called `Notes at Night` and I want to use a more dark keyboard in background. How can I set it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-to-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard background color in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-to-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Swift you need: `textField.keyboardAppearance = .Dark`

Answer (score 2):

use property of textfield keyboardAppearence