# Swift: How can I change the color of keyboard background and lettering?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard

I am building a project for iOS8 in swift. The default and dark options for keyboard in xcode do not go with the color theme for my app design.

Is there a simple way for to change the colors in the keybaord?

Comment: You can find a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729205/6481734

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't change the look and feel of the system keyboard. Even if you did many people don't even use the default keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 8 apple introduced [custom keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) extension.

> A custom keyboard replaces the system keyboard for users who want
>   capabilities such as a novel text input method or the ability to enter
>   text in a language not otherwise supported in iOS. The essential
>   function of a custom keyboard is simple: Respond to taps, gestures, or
>   other input events and provide text, in the form of an unattributed
>   NSString object, at the text insertion point of the current text input
>   object.

And here's some useful tutorials about how to create custom keyboard :

- http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension/
- https://www.weheartswift.com/make-custom-keyboard-ios-8-using-swift/