# change the background custom keyboard with switch- or buttons To be presented in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

How To add Image To background custom keyboard?
I want to set the number of images they have the background and the user can select the image that suits him

I use the language of "swift"

Comment: [this](http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension/) can help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change keyboard background color in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-to-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios)

Comment: You had asked this same question [6hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909797/change-the-background-color-keyboard) ago? Please elaborate what you were not understanding and what you are not understanding from the answers?

Comment: I want to change the whole look, but that I could do if I have that way ... I'm trying to make a button with which I can change the background color of the red color of the keyboard or any other color that does not matter ... I have KeyboardViewController it is the keyboard And it's also the ViewController main window ... I want the button to be in a ViewController and he gave a command to the keyboard to change color

Comment: How To add Image To background custom keyboard?I want to set the number of images they have the background and the user can select the image that suits him

Answer (score 0):

This have been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-to-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios).
Anyhow:

You need to change the `keyboardAppearance` for a certain textfield you want the keyboard to be changed for. You can do this via the differnet `UIKeyboardAppearance`s - more about the different types of appearances you can find in apple's [UITextInputTraits API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html).

i.e:

```
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

Would look like:

[image: Dark appearance]

```
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceLight;
```

Would look like:

[image]

Comment: @DevelopApple No need to pay at all. Just ask for what you need, and I'll direct you to tutorials or explain to you everything you'll ask for in the limitation of my knowledge right here (:

Comment: I can not put a picture maybe it would explain you more my question

Comment: @DevelopApple Edit your question then , and explain what exacly you need. Do you need to put pictures for the buttons? A background image?

Comment: @DevelopApple Please use this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to guide you for adding pictures to your question.

Comment: @DevelopApple I editted the question with pictures. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to change the whole look, but that I could do if I have that way ...
I'm trying to make a button with which I can change the background color of the red color of the keyboard or any other color that does not matter ...
I have KeyboardViewController it is the keyboard
And it's also the ViewController main window ...

I want the button to be in a ViewController and he gave a command to the keyboard to change color

Comment: Yes, I want to change the buttons and the background ... This custom keyboard

Comment: @DevelopApple Take a look in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222040/swift-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-keyboard-background-and-lettering

   let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: I have willing keyboard sounds including a personal choice ... I only have the color change personal choice please if you can help me personally I thank you very much
I'm still new at this so I can hardly explain my question

Comment: How To add Image To background custom keyboard?I want to set the number of images they have the background and the user can select the image that suits him