# Tabbar of TabbarController tint color

Tags: objective-c, ios

When i used this code in iPhone 4.3 simulator , i got this error but when run it on iPhone 5 simulator ,it's worked without errors .

**Code**

```
    UITabBarController *tabB = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabB.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255.0 green:150.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

tabB.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:187.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:38.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];            
tabB.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:hc,bt, nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabB animated:YES];
```

**Error**

```
-[UITabBar setTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78787c0
2012-04-24 10:59:46.776 welcomeKidsWebsite[10357:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBar setTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78787c0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01bcd5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d21313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01bcf0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01b3e966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01b3e522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   welcomeKidsWebsite                  0x0005ac8e -[KidsWelcomeViewController GotoBooks:] + 622
    6   UIKit                               0x00e1f4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    7   UIKit                               0x00eaf799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x00eb1c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    9   UIKit                               0x00eb07d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    10  UIKit                               0x00e43ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    11  UIKit                               0x00e24c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    12  UIKit                               0x00e29f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x02528992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01bae944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01b0ecf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01b0bf83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01b0b840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01b0b761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x025271c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x02527289 GSEventRun + 115
    21  UIKit                               0x00e2dc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  welcomeKidsWebsite                  0x000024ac main + 188
    23  welcomeKidsWebsite                  0x000023e5 start + 53
```

Comment: because this setTintColor: is added in ios5 so you dont have it in ios4.3

Comment: @AalokParikh you should put this as an answer, since it IS the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to make this version independent is:

```
 if ([tabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
        [tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:color];
 }
```

In IOS 5 this will set the tabbar tintcolor and in lower versions it wont crash

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `tintColor` is only available in iOS 5.0 and later. The clue was that the 4.3 simulator is saying `unrecognized selector sent to instance` which basically means the method doesn't exist.

You'll need to do one of the following:

> - Set your minimum required iOS to 5.0.
> - Only apply the tint when running on iOS 5.0 or greater.
> - Use an alternative method supported by both versions.

Documentation Excerpt:

> tintColor
>
> The tint color to apply to the tab bar background.
>   @property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: do you know alternative method ?

Comment: I've previously used a method like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version) to enable the tint for users on iOS 5 only, however depending on your application that might not be viable.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
tabB.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255.0 green:150.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```