# support iOS 5.1 NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey [do not backup] without Lion installed?

Tags: ios, ios5

I see it's apparently possible to [submit apps without Lion installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376127/ios-submission-without-lion), but my app downloads some large files, which need to be saved according to [Apple storage guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).

Including the code below, I can't even compile due to `Use of undeclared identifier 'NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey'`:

```
-(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.1")) {
        assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                      forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
        if(!success){
            NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

How can I keep using this code while I've only got iOS 5.0 SDK in xcode?

(or is my desire moot because I literally cannot tell my app it supports iOS 5.1?)

- (`SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO` comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/194309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a definition of that string constant if the ios version is not 5.1.

Here is how my implementation looks like:

```
+ (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSString*) path
    {           
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.01"))
        {
            const char* folderPath = [_privateDirectoryPath fileSystemRepresentation];
            u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
            int result = setxattr(folderPath, kMobileBackupAttrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
            return result == 0;
        } 
        else
        {
    #ifndef __IPHONE_5_1
    #define NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey @"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey"
    #endif
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            ASSERT_CLASS(url, NSURL);
            BOOL success = [url setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                          forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey 
                                           error: &error];
            //Assert success                
            return success;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Haha is that constant's value literally just the string of the constant's name?

Comment: Yes, if you print it, in iOS 5.1, it is just the constant's name. In any case, it won't be used when the ios version is less than 5.1. I could have used any value.