# Determine Version of iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

I am trying to setup some code that is different on iOS 5.0.1 than it is one iOS 5.1 and higher.  Is there an if statement to determine it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] == 5.0)
{
// Do something
}


else if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] == 5.1)
{
// Do something
}
else
{
// Do something
}
```

Comment: This is wrong for reasons outlined in comments to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3341214/118721 (see the accepted answer there for a correct solution).

Answer (score 0):

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
```