# Facebook and Twitter Integration Based on Both iOS4 and iOS5 Versions

Tags: facebook, ios5, twitter, ios4, xcode4.2

I am new to Facebook and Twitter integrations. I am able to integrate them in individual versions, i.e `iOS4` and `iOS5`.

I am facing difficulty in checking the condition that based on the version, need to integrate Twitter and Facebook functionalities.

Can anyone suggest me regarding this.

Comment: thanks for editing Mr.Daniel.actually i am new one to ask questions here.and suggest me if any mistakes are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS version check

```
NSArray *versionCompatibility = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ( 5 == [[versionCompatibility objectAtIndex:0] intValue] ) { /// iOS5 is installed

    // Put iOS-5 code here

} else { /// iOS4 is installed

    // Put iOS-4 code here         

}
```

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

So you can find the iOS version with this also

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController") != nil) { /// iOS5 is installed

    // Put iOS-5 code here

} else { /// iOS4 is installed

    // Put iOS-4 code here         

}
```

Or Can Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339787/1132951) out the most up-voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339787/1132951) for this type of question

Comment: At the time of tap on sharing button ie at the time of integration of FB or Twitter, or in appDelegate for global excess :)

Comment: thanks for ur valuable reply. it works for me. once again thank alot @Aalok Parikh

Comment: YWC and happy to help and also my answer is working for you :)

Comment: I and many more developers will discourage version checking. Rather you should do a feature check. If there is no Twitter framework, then use a fallback. But avoid assuming too much by checking system version numbers etc.

Comment: may i know what is fallback?@Daniel. actually i dont know about that.

Comment: So does this one is good @Daniel If so please up-vote or just remove down-vote