# What will happen to users running a lower version of IOS if new code is called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am fairly new to iOS Development and I've always wondered if a user running my application on iOS 4 were to try and run this code:

```
//POST TWEET//
- (void)showTweetSheet
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet =
    [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch(result) {
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                break;
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                break;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                NSLog(@"Tweet Sheet has been dismissed.");
            }];
        });
    };
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this cool picture I found on @Pickr_"];
    //  Add an URL to the Tweet.  You can add multiple URLs.
    if (![tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageHost]]){
        NSLog(@"Unable to add the URL!");
    }
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Tweet sheet has been presented.");
    }];
}
```

What would happen?  Would the application just terminate with an error or will the code just not run?  And how do I properly implement features that are OS specific?  Would I just use something like this:

```
NSString *DeviceVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int DeviceVersionInt = [DeviceVersion intValue];
if (DeviceVersionInt > 5)
{
    //do something.
}
else
{
    //don't do a thing.
}
```

Comment: You've basically got the right idea here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will crash on iOS 4 if you write iOS5 features without checking if they are available or not. Try to implement Twitter like this

> ```
> Class twClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");
> if (!twClass) // Framework not available, older iOS
> {
>     //use iOS4 SDK to implement Twitter framework
> }
> else {
>     //use Apple provided default Twitter framework
> ```
>
> }

Make sure you have added Twitter Framework with weak link.

Comment: Checking for features is better than checking a version number, +1

Comment: What to do you mean by using a weak link with the Twitter Framework?  I set it to "Optional" in my projects settings, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Id imagine that it would work the same as with any other api. If you link against a function which is not in a previous version, the program will crash on an attempt to call the function. Therefore, version switches are used, as you demonstrated, to avoid crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The app would crash.  If you want to implement features based on iOS, you can use a variety of methods.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version).