# Best practice for checking if DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND exists?

Tags: ios, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

Apple's documentation [clearly states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is only available in iOS 5 or later.  What is the correct way to check if it's available in the runtime environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check the version of the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version) and see if it is greater or equal to 5

Answer (score 4):

If you are building against iOS 5 SDK or later, it is safe to simply call `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)` and check for a non-NULL return value.