# Floating point comparing with >= versus (> or ==)

Tags: ios, floating-point

I noticed the following in a chunk of code I'm maintaining/extending:

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (systemVersion > 3.2 || systemVersion == 3.2 ) {
    //Stuff
}
```

I know floating point can result in some odd comparison behaviors due to precision, but would the above behave any differently than the chunk of code below?

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (systemVersion >= 3.2) {
    //Stuff
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the same even if you throw NaNs and infinities at it. :)

Comment: Please tell me you don't have to deal with code that stores version numbers as floats... :-(

Comment: @MarkDickinson It looks like the version number is stored as an NSString, which someone before me decided to turn into a float (clobbering the minor version number)... As I go through the code I'm hoping to change it to match [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/264775), but I'm hesitant to change this outside the segments I'm working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same thing.  In many compilers, the resulting machine instructions are exactly the same (although I can't say for sure that's true for clang).

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't. I think this code, that turned out this way by accident (maybe after a couple of small adjustments).