# Knowing iOS version

Tags: ios, version

Is there a way of knowing if I am running in iOS 5 (or less) or 6 (or later)?

I am using Google API for directions in iOS 5 and I would like to use Apple's in iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answers your question. Check iPhone iOS Version
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/1368748**

Comment: I think this covers it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the iOS version from:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

In general, its a better practice to test if the feature you need is available or not, rather than relying on specific iOS versions.  As @mprivat mentions, `NSClassFromString` is one method for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a specific class that was introduced in the new OS instead of trying to ask the OS itself for a version.

For example:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UICollectionView")) {
    // It's iOS 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are programming against iOS 5 you can use the more recent method of checking for weakly linked libraries by just calling the class's `class` method, which returns nil if it's not supported.

As an example (taken from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW6)):

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController class]) {
   // Create an instance of the class and use it.
}
else {
   // The print interaction controller is not available.
}
```

This requires LLVM and Clang, but as your supporting iOS5 and iOS6, you should be using this anyway.